# Custom menu item in Windows context menu works incorrectly

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, context-menu

I added menu item to Windows context menu based on this tutorial: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/)
I run BAT file instead of notepad.exe. My BAT file runs "del" command. It works fine with all files except files ending with ".exe". System runs the executable instead of running the script. I guess there is conflict somewhere in registry. The point of script is that del command does not move files to bin.

How do I repair it?

EDIT 1:

BAT file contains:

```
@echo off
del %1 /F /Q > nul
exit
```

output from reg query "HKCR_CURRENT_USER..*\shell\QuickDel\command":

```
C:\MyWindowsScripts\QuickDel.bat "%1"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your batch file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your batch file **and** output from `reg query "HKCR\*\shell\YourMenuName\Command"`